# Trees and arrows

Tags: trees

I need to draw an arrow, using `\draw[semithick,->] (t)..controls +(south west:5) and +(south:5) .. (wh);`.

I want the arrow to connect `e3` at the bottom of the following tree to the single `e3` occurring higher up in it:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
    \usepackage{tikz-qtree}
    \usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
    \usepackage{ulem}

    \begin{document}

     \begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.{$<$t$_{1}$,\hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack$ \hspace{0.3cm} $\rbrack$, $\lbrack$ \hspace{0.3cm} $\rbrack$ $>$} [.{$<$(e$_{3}$ $\rightarrow$ t$_{1}$) $\rightarrow$ t$_{1}$),\hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack$ e$_{3}$ $\rbrack$ $>$} \node(wh){something} ;]
[.{$<$(e$_{3}$  $\rightarrow$ t$_{1}$), \hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack$ e$_{2}$ $\rbrack$, \hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack$ \hcancel{e$_{3}$}
 \thinspace $\rbrack$ $>$ } [.{e$_{3}$}  ]
[.\node[draw]{{$<$t$_{1}$, \hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack$ e$_{2}$ $\rbrack$, \hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack$ e$_{3}$ $\rbrack$ $>$ }}; 
[.\node[draw]{e$_{2}$ }; ]
[.{$<$(e$_{2}$  $\rightarrow$ t$_{1}$), \hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack$ e$_{3}$ $\rbrack$ $>$} [.{$<$(e$_{3}$ $\rightarrow$ e$_{2}$  $\rightarrow$ t$_{1}$),\hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack$ $\emptyset$ $\rbrack$ $>$}  {$<$(e$_{3}$ $\rightarrow$ e$_{2}$  $\rightarrow$ t$_{1}$),\hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack$ $\emptyset$ $\rbrack$ $>$} ]
[.\node[draw]{e$_{3}$ }; 
[. e$_{3}$; ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you forget a `}` somewhere? I can't compile this code.

Comment: It works for me... strange

Comment: I also can't get the MWE to compile (an undefined control sequence error). It looks like there are several places whether `_` is used outside math mode. I don't see a reason to keep going in and out of math mode within your type specifications. I would recommend posting a much simpler MWE (or at least a screenshot of the output you get iwth the one you posted) so we can see what's going on with the arrow. The code snippet for the arrow looks fine -- you should just be able to put that after the last bracket in the tree and before `\end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: How about this code instead

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `\node`s with names for those elements and then use the names to connect them:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
    \usepackage{tikz-qtree}
    \usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
    \usepackage{ulem}

\def\hcancel#1{}% provissional definition; delete this line in your actual code

    \begin{document}

     \begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree 
[.{$<$t$_{1}$,\hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack$ \hspace{0.3cm} $\rbrack$, $\lbrack$ \hspace{0.3cm} $\rbrack$ $>$} 
  [.{$<$(e$_{3}$ $\rightarrow$ t$_{1}$) $\rightarrow$ t$_{1}$),\hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack$ e$_{3}$ $\rbrack$ $>$} \node(wh){something} ;
  ]
  [.{$<$(e$_{3}$  $\rightarrow$ t$_{1}$), \hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack$ e$_{2}$ $\rbrack$, \hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack$ \hcancel{e$_{3}$}
 \thinspace $\rbrack$ $>$ } 
    [. \node (ue) {e$_{3}$};  ]
    [.\node[draw]{{$<$t$_{1}$, \hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack$ e$_{2}$ $\rbrack$, \hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack$ e$_{3}$ $\rbrack$ $>$ }}; 
      [.\node[draw]{e$_{2}$ }; ]
      [.{$<$(e$_{2}$  $\rightarrow$ t$_{1}$), \hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack$ e$_{3}$ $\rbrack$ $>$} 
        [.{$<$(e$_{3}$ $\rightarrow$ e$_{2}$  $\rightarrow$ t$_{1}$),\hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack$ $\emptyset$ $\rbrack$ $>$}  {$<$(e$_{3}$ $\rightarrow$ e$_{2}$  $\rightarrow$ t$_{1}$),\hspace{0.1cm} \\$\lbrack$ $\emptyset$ $\rbrack$ $>$} 
        ]
        [.\node[draw]{e$_{3}$ }; 
          [. \node (le) {e$_{3}$}; ] 
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
\draw[semithick,->] 
  (le)..controls +(south west:5) and +(south:5) .. (ue);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since I didn't know where the \hcancel command came from, I provided a simple definition

```
\def\hcancel#1{}
```

to make the example code compilable. Remove that definition in your actual code.

Comment: @user65526, if this answer answers your question, you can say thanks by [upvoting and accepting it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).