# Arrows in Forest

Tags: tikz-arrows, forest, linguistics

How can I keep arrows in the `forest` environment from overlapping with tree elements?
[image: I want the arrows to be like the red one.]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}

(2)\quad Where will the director order the actor to stand? \\

\begin{forest} for tree={calign=fixed edge angles, calign primary angle=-70, calign secondary angle=70}
[CP [DP$_i$ [where, roof, name=where in]]
    [C$'$   [C \\ will$_j$, name=will in]
            [TP [DP     [the director, roof]]
                [T$'$   [$t_j$, name=will out]
                        [vP [v \\ order, name=order in]
                            [VP [DP$_m$ [the actor, roof]]
                                [V$'$   [$t_k$, name=order out]
                                        [TP [PRO$_m$]
                                            [T$'$   [T \\ to]
                                                    [VP [V \\ stand]
                                                        [$t_i$, name=where out]]]]]]]]]]]
    \draw[->] (will out) to[out=-90, in=-90] (will in);
    \draw[->] (where out) to[out=-90, in=-90] (where in);
    \draw[->] (order out) to[out=-90, in=-90] (order in);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can try the `looseness` option for the arrow and mayby slightly change the `in` angle

Comment: I changed one arrow to `\draw[->] (will out.south west) to[out=-135, in=-90, looseness=1.5] (will in.south west);`, maybe it still looks adequate for you ...

Comment: This answer may be helpful for you to understand how to add control points to guide the arrow around the subject DP. The example there uses `tikz-qtree` rather than `forest` to draw the tree itself, but that doesn't make a difference -- both use normal `tikz` arrows. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251040/42880

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments, probably the easiest way would be to play around with the `in`/`out` angles and/or the `looseness` of the arrow, to see which path doesn't cross the DPs and still looks alright to you.

For example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}
    
    (2)\quad Where will the director order the actor to stand? \\
    
    \begin{forest} for tree={calign=fixed edge angles, calign primary angle=-70, calign secondary angle=70}
        [CP [DP$_i$ [where, roof, name=where in]]
        [C$'$   [C \\ will$_j$, name=will in]
        [TP [DP     [the director, roof]]
        [T$'$   [$t_j$, name=will out]
        [vP [v \\ order, name=order in]
        [VP [DP$_m$ [the actor, roof]]
        [V$'$   [$t_k$, name=order out]
        [TP [PRO$_m$]
        [T$'$   [T \\ to]
        [VP [V \\ stand]
        [$t_i$, name=where out]]]]]]]]]]]
        \draw[->] (will out) to[out=-120, in=-120,looseness=1.5] (will in);
        \draw[->] (where out) to[out=-120, in=-90] (where in);
        \draw[->] (order out) to[out=-120, in=-120,looseness=1.5] (order in);
    \end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```

---

**Unrelated to the question itself:**

If you aren't hardcoding `(2)\quad` just for this MWE but in your document as well, I would recommend switching to a package for numbered examples (and linguistic glosses). My personal favorite is `expex`, but there are many other options like `linguex`, `gb4e`, or `covington`.