# Draw an arrow in a syntactic tree (tikzpicture)

Tags: arrows, tikz-trees

How could I draw an arrow to the right of the dotted circle and write some text after it, e.g.
-> /a/?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\tikzset{sibling distance=5em}
\draw[blue, dotted] (-.5,-2.2) circle (40pt);
\node (top) {}
child[blue] {node {$\phi$}} 
child [blue] {node  {}
child [blue]{node {T}}
child {node {}
child[red] {node {Mood}}
child [red]{node {}
child {node {Asp}}
child {node {}
child {node {Cause}}
child {node {Proc}}
}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: welcome! This question has come up several times before on this site. Check out https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250714/trees-and-arrows/250786 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251006/drawing-node-arrows/251040 as a starting place.

Comment: Thanks for posting those answers, but those don't answer my question :)

Comment: Why are you loading `tikz-qtree` but not using it? The basic `tikz` methods for trees are really not very useful compared to what you can achieve much more simply with `tikz-qtree` or even better, `forest`.